# Can you reduce the number of contour lines?

Tags: qgis

Using QGIS, is it possible to reduce the number of contour lines in a hypsography (topographic) layer? Mine has them every 5 meters, which is more than I need and it makes the map awfully busy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the contour elevation as an attribute?  If so, you could work on a selection method to select only those that are multiples of 10m, for example.  An easy way to do this is to use a python calculator to calculate a new field that returns the modulo (remainder) of the elevation field divided by 10.

eg:
modulo = elevation % 10

You can then do a definition query on your data so that it will only display those where the modulo field = 0.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like an idea worth looking into. Thanks.